# separate html and php

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I am very new to HTML and PHP and can not figure out how to separate them properly.

```
<html>
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deviation")
 or die(mysql_error());
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
  Print "<tr>";
  <input type="radio" name="chassi" value=<?php $info['chassi']/>  $info['chassi']
<br />  
}
<html>
```

This is as you might see a wild mix of PHP and HTML code. It is in a HTML form. I want to use the PHP while loop but at the same time use the HTML input. How do I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is the right time for you to understand http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/17/getting-started-with-php-templating/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to add php tags!**

Add a `<?php` and a `?>` at the start and end of any php code!

For example you would write something like this:

```
<?php $variable = "Something"; ?>
<div><?php echo $variable ?></div>

//Would show
<div>Something</div>
```

To fix your code you should try:

```
<html>
    <!--Head and body tags missing?-->
    <?php
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deviation")
        or die(mysql_error());

        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
        { ?>
            <tr><td>
                <input type="radio" name="chassi" value="<?php echo $info['chassi'] ?>" />
            <td></tr>
        <?php } ?>
    <!--Closing body tag here?-->
 <html>
```

To clear up from comment below:

```
<div>Some text</div> <!--This is html-->
<?php echo $var //This is PHP ?>
```

To add these together you must use `<?php` at the start then `?>` at the end of any PHP. Perhaps its worth reading the PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: You have forgot `""` around value If I'm not wrong and also an `echo` for the php variables

Comment: You still didn't defined separate lol... You just put php between html tags and put html in a .php file....

Comment: @Bondye Thats how PHP works, whats confusing you about it?

Comment: @Sam What? How does PHP work? PHP also works without HTML. Plz read https://encrypted.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define+separate

Comment: @Bondye PHP creates HTML, then sends that to the client machine!

Comment: @Bondye Please read the first sentence on this PHP manual page -> http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to add opening a closing php tags to all php code sections like this:

```
<html>
<?php $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deviation")
 or die(mysql_error());
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{ 
  echo "<tr>"; ?>
  <input type="radio" name="chassi" value=<?php $info['chassi']/>  $info['chassi']
<br />  
<?php } ?>
<html>
```

Comment: where is the `echo` for $info??

Answer (score 0):

Every php code should be in  and every should not be part of it. If you want it, you can echo it out like echo "";

```
<table>
<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deviation")
 or die(mysql_error());
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
?>
  <tr><td>
  <input type="radio" name="chassi" value="<?php echo $info['chassi'] ?>" /> <?php echo $info['chassi'];?>
</td></tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

your HTML code also be properly tagged. For loop should have proper table rows "" and its should have  with contents in it. You have to learn HTML and PHP basics.

Comment: Seem to be a working answer than others here but consider wrapping value's value inside quotes

Comment: thanks for the correction.. Corrected!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the while shorthand. and when output variables make sure you echo in HTML

```
<html>
<?php
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deviation") or die(mysql_error());
  while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) : 
?>
  <tr>
  <input type="radio" name="chassi" value=<?php echo $info['chassi']?>/> <?php echo $info['chassi'] ?>
  <br />  
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<html>
```